# Simple Shell in C

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix

I am working on a school project which is basically creating a simple shell in UNIX.
But I'm stuck with history part of my project.The explanation which is about history part is explained below:

history – This command is for maintaining a history of commands previously issued.

o history - print up to the 10 most recently entered commands in your shell.

o ! number - A user should be able to repeat a previously issued command by
typing ! number, where number indicates which command to repeat.

Note that ! 1 is for repeating the command numbered 1 in the list of commands returned by
history, and ! -1 is for repeating the last command.

And my code till history part is here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define CREATE_FLAGS (O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_APPEND)
#define CREATE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)
#define CREATE_FLAG (O_WRONLY| O_CREAT| O_TRUNC)
#define MAXCHARNUM 128 
#define MAXARGNUM 32 
char *argsexec[MAXARGNUM];
char str[MAXCHARNUM];
char *path;
char *name;

struct Node
{

  pid_t pid;
  char *pname;
  int index;
  struct Node *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Node *NodePtr;

NodePtr list = NULL;

void addJob(NodePtr *currentPtr, pid_t pid, char *name, int indx)
{

  NodePtr newPtr, prePtr, curPtr;
  newPtr = malloc(sizeof(Node));

  if (newPtr != NULL )
  {

    newPtr->pid = pid;
    newPtr->pname = name;
    newPtr->index = indx;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
    prePtr = NULL;
    curPtr = *currentPtr;

    while (curPtr != NULL )
    {
      prePtr = curPtr;
      curPtr = curPtr->nextPtr;
    }

    if (prePtr == NULL )
    {
      newPtr->nextPtr = *currentPtr;
      *currentPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else
    {
      prePtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
      newPtr->nextPtr = curPtr;
    }
  }
}

void printJob(NodePtr curPtr)
{
  if (curPtr == NULL )
  {
    printf("Running: List is empty.\n");
    printf("Terminated: List is empty.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Running:\n");

    while (curPtr != NULL )
    {
      printf("[%d] --> %s\n", curPtr->index, curPtr->pname);
      curPtr = curPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    printf("Finished:\n");

    while (curPtr != NULL )
    {
      printf("[%d] --> %s (pid = %d)\n", curPtr->index, curPtr->pname,
          curPtr->pid);
      curPtr = curPtr->nextPtr;
    }
  }
}

void ioredirection()
{

  int input = -1, output = -1, append = -1;
  int k, d, fdinput, fdoutput;
  for (k = 0; argsexec[k] != NULL ; k++)
  {

    if (strcmp(argsexec[k], "<") == 0)
    {
      argsexec[k] = NULL;
      input = k;
      d = 1;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argsexec[k], ">") == 0)
    {
      argsexec[k] = NULL;
      output = k;
      d = 2;
    }
    else if (strcmp(argsexec[k], ">>") == 0)
    {
      argsexec[k] = NULL;
      append = k;
      d = 3;
    }
    if (d == 1)
    {
      fdinput = open(argsexec[input + 1], O_RDONLY, 0);
      dup2(fdinput, STDIN_FILENO);
      close(fdinput);
      execvp(argsexec[0], argsexec);
    }
    if (d == 2)
    {
      int x, y;
      char buffer[1024];

      fdinput = open(argsexec[output - 1], O_RDONLY);
      fdoutput = open(argsexec[output + 1], CREATE_FLAG, CREATE_MODE);

      dup2(fdoutput, STDOUT_FILENO);
      x = read(fdinput, buffer, 1024);
      write(fdoutput, buffer, x);

      close(fdinput);
      close(fdoutput);

      for (y = output; y < MAXARGNUM - 2; y++)
        argsexec[y] = argsexec[y + 2];
      argsexec[MAXARGNUM - 2] = NULL;
    }
    if (d == 3)
    {
      int x, y;
      char buffer[1024];

      fdinput = open(argsexec[output - 1], O_RDONLY);
      fdoutput = open(argsexec[output + 1], CREATE_FLAGS, CREATE_MODE);

      x = read(fdinput, buffer, 1024);
      write(fdoutput, buffer, x);

      close(fdinput);
      close(fdoutput);
    }
  }

}
void add_path(char **dir, const char *begin, const char *end) //do the memory allocations, and add to the specified arrays.
{
  if (end == begin)
  {
    begin = " ";
    end = begin + 1;
  }
  size_t len = end - begin;
  *dir = malloc(len + 1);
  memmove(*dir, begin, len);
  (*dir)[len] = '\0';

}

size_t tokenize(const char *path, char **dirs, size_t max_dirs, char delim) //tokenize the given input, with the given delimiter
{                        //returns the size of the splitted parts of the string.
  const char *begin = path;
  const char *end;
  size_t num_dirs = 0;

  while (num_dirs < max_dirs && (end = strchr(begin, delim)) != 0)
  {
    add_path(&dirs[num_dirs++], begin, end);
    begin = end + 1;
  }
  if (num_dirs < max_dirs && *begin != '\0')
    add_path(&dirs[num_dirs++], begin, begin + strlen(begin));
  return num_dirs;
}

void clearArgs()
{

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < MAXARGNUM; ++i)
  {
    argsexec[i] = NULL;
  }
}

int Ampersand()
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; argsexec[i] != NULL ; i++)
  {
    if (strcmp(argsexec[i], "&") == 0)
    {
      return 1;
    }
    else
    {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}

void Setup()
{

  while (1)
  {
    path = malloc((MAXCHARNUM + 1) * sizeof(char));
    clearArgs();

    fprintf(stderr, "333sh: ", NULL );
    gets(str);  //get the next commands

    while (strlen(str) == 0)
    { //if the user enters empty string or space, ignore this input, read again.
      fprintf(stderr, "333sh: ", NULL );
      gets(str);
    }

    size_t commands = tokenize(str, argsexec, MAXARGNUM, ' ');
    const char *path = getenv("PATH");  //get the system's path   
    ioredirection();
    char * const arguments[] =
    { argsexec[0], argsexec[1], argsexec[2], argsexec[3], argsexec[4],
        argsexec[5], argsexec[6], argsexec[7], (void*) NULL };

    name = argsexec[0];
    pid_t pid = fork();
    wait(NULL );

    if (Ampersand())
    {
      if (pid == 0)
      {
        int in = 1;
        addJob(&list, pid, name, in);

      }
    }
    if (pid == 0)
    {
      if (!Ampersand())
      {

        if (path == NULL )
        {  //execl part
          execl(path, argsexec[0], argsexec[1], argsexec[2], argsexec[3],
              argsexec[4], argsexec[5], argsexec[6], argsexec[7], NULL );
        }
        else if (strcmp(argsexec[0], "dir") == 0 && argsexec[1] == NULL )
        {
          system("ls");
        }

        else if (strcmp(argsexec[0], "clr") == 0)
        {
          system("clear");
        }
        else if (strcmp(argsexec[0], "cd") == 0 && argsexec[1] == NULL )
        {
          system("pwd");
        }
        else if (strcmp(argsexec[0], "list_jobs") == 0 && argsexec[1] == NULL )
        {
          printJob(list);

        }
        else
        {  //execvp part

          execvp(argsexec[0], arguments);
        }

      }
    }
  }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  Setup();
  return 0;

}
```

So how can i design a history part of this project ? Any idea would be appreciated.And sorry for asking that much long code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to create an array of 10 pointers to NULL initially. Add a routine `update_history(<cmd issued>)` or such that you call after every command you allow in your shell. It should:

(1) 1st call: `malloc()` space for the first command issued, and store the pointer to the
               heap area in the array's first position
(2) Later calls: check the array for the first position with a NULL pointer, and store a pointer to the command there (using malloc() again). If you find no NULL pointer in the array (history is 10 commands long), go to (3)
(3) execute another new routine `move_history(cmd issued)`. It moves the second array position (pointer) to the first, the 3rd to the 2nd, ..., the 10th to the 9th, and inserts a pointer to where `<cmd_issued>` is stored on the heap (using another malloc()) into the last array position. Don't forget to `free()` the heap memory that was allocated for the formerly first element that is no longer tracked.

You could then very easily print out the entire history (print through the array of pointers until you find a NULL pointer, but no more than 10 p/os; and print the command history numbers 1-10 (or 0-9) before the strings); and to print a particular command, you know in which array row the pointer to it is (if 1-based numbering, in row `i-1`). You can then read it and re-issue the command (don't forget to make that part of your history too).